# zooming ,scrolling and updating of images from database like google map

Tags: php, jquery, html

i am working on an application that display images from the database. i wants to add the functionality of map in my application. like

1. i have created an invisible grid and showing the images from database in that grid. each image in the database has the address like (row, col). i want to display all the images in their respective grid id.
2. scrolling (it should send the request to the server on scroll and update the page with the new images.)
3. zooming (it should zoom in ir out, and send the request to the server and update the page with the new images with the large or small size depands on the zoom in or out value.)
4. i dont wants to download all the images , i just want to update the specific area in case of zooming, scrolling etc.

following is my code, that i m using for displaying and scrolling.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <style type="text/css">

#overscroll { width: 500px; height: 500px; overflow: hidden; border: solid 1px #000; margin: 30px auto; position: relative; }
#overscroll ul { width: 2500px; margin:0; padding: 0; }
#overscroll li { display: block; float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #FFF; }
#overscroll li.alt { background-color: #C00; }
#overscroll li.no-drag { background-color: #000; color: #FFF; }
#overscroll li.last { clear: both; visibility: hidden; height: 0; padding: 0; }
  </style>


 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
 $dbCon = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
 $db = mysql_select_db("db");
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM images";
 $result = mysql_query ($sql);
 $rows = 3;
 $cols = 3;
 $zoom = 1;

 echo "<div id='overscroll'>";
 echo "<table width='600px' border='1'>";
 for ($i=1; $i<=$rows; $i++){

echo "<tr>";
for ($j=1; $j<=$cols; $j++){
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if ($data[3] != '')
        echo "<td align='center'><img src='{$data[3]}' width=100 height=100></td>";
    else
    echo "<td align='center'><img src='abc.jpg' width=100 height=100></td>";    
    }
echo "</tr>";
 }  


 ?>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.overscroll.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(o){  
        o = $("#overscroll").overscroll({
            cancelOn: '.no-drag',
            //hoverThumbs: true,
            //persistThumbs: true,
            //showThumbs: false,
            scrollLeft: 200,
            scrollTop: 100
        }).on('overscroll:dragstart overscroll:dragend overscroll:driftstart overscroll:driftend', function(event){
            console.log(event.type);
        });
        $("#link").click(function(){
            if(!o.data("dragging")) {
                console.log("clicked!");
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i am using a javascript plugin.

shall i use html5 canvas ? for that kind of application, if yes, then can anyone send me some reference of open-source. how can i accomplish this task ? i have checked ajax-zoom, and other map apis, but its not the solution suitable for me. i cannot work on geo-server.

please help

Answer (score 0):

Investigate using http://openlayers.org/